# Python - Not identifying Null values even though it is present in the Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading a csv file and creating a Pandas Dataframe out of it. It has many columns of different datatypes.

The column "localHour" is assumed to contain only numeric values but unfortunately it contains "null" values as it can be seen in Microsoft Excel / Open Office application or even the unique() method in Pandas also reveals that it contains "null" values

```
df1['localHour'].unique()

Out[78]: 
array(['9', '12', '17', '16', '22', '19', '11', '15', '6', '18', '7', '21',
       '13', '20', '23', '10', '14', '8', '5', '3', '1', '0', '2', '4',
       'null', '-1'], dtype=object)
```

**But surprisingly isnull() method does not find any null values in the column. I am not able to understand what is wrong here**.

```
df1['localHour'].isnull().values.any()
Out[80]: False

df1['localHour'].isnull().unique()    
Out[81]: array([False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `unique()` here is just showing that there is only one boolean output of your call to `isnull()`, which is `False`.  in other words, there are no recognized null entries in this vector.

Comment: yes @andrew_reece that's where my confusion lies

Comment: See my answer below.  My comment above was referring to your statement: `unique() method in Pandas also reveals that it contains "null" values`.  That's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help from few folks here, I found out that there is a parameter **"na_values"** for Pandas' read_csv method. If we pass the values (that we think should be interpreted as NaN), then those values wherever it is present in the Dataframe will be interpreted as "NaN" instead of a string value.

For example in my case the string "null" should be interpreted as "NaN". So if I create a Dataframe with na_values parameter, then my Dataframe will not be having string "null" values. All those values are replaced as NaN as can be seen from below command outputs.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Train_Dataset.csv",na_values="null")

df1['localHour'].unique()
Out[97]: 
array([  9.,  12.,  17.,  16.,  22.,  19.,  11.,  15.,   6.,  18.,   7.,
        21.,  13.,  20.,  23.,  10.,  14.,   8.,   5.,   3.,   1.,   0.,
         2.,   4.,  nan,  -1.])

df1['localHour'].isnull().values.any()  
Out[98]: True

df1['localHour'].isnull().unique()
Out[99]: array([False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

*Additional Note : If anybody wants to mentiond more values in "na_values" parameter then mention all of them as a list*

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("Train_Dataset.csv",na_values=["null","Null","nUlL"])
```

Useful Reference Link - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 3):

Those aren't numbers, those are string representations of numbers.
And the string `'null'` is not understood by Python to represent a `None` or `NaN` or other similar null reference.  As-is, `'null'` is just seen as the string containing the characters `n-u-l-l`.

Use `to_numeric()` to convert the column, then you'll see the null value is correctly identified.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"localHour":['9', '12', '17', '16', '22', '19', 
                                 '11', '15', '6', '18', '7', '21',
                                 '13', '20', '23', '10', '14', '8', 
                                 '5', '3', '1', '0', '2', '4', 'null', '-1']})
df1.localHour = pd.to_numeric(df1.localHour, errors="coerce")

df1.localHour.tail()
21    0.0
22    2.0
23    4.0
24    NaN
25   -1.0
Name: localHour, dtype: float64

df1.localHour.tail().isnull()
21    False
22    False
23    False
24     True
25    False
Name: localHour, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Great find. But as you have already identified the issue, how to overcome this while reading the csv file. Because ideally the csv file may contain hundreds of columns and I can't find where string "null" values would be there. Any inputs on how to resolve this in a more generic way ?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Look to the `dtype` and `converter` arguments in the [`read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to generalize beyond the specific problem you raised in your post.

Comment: Your answer is helpful to me in converting columns individually but in a more generic sense I think I have got an option. There is a parameter "na_values" in pd.read_csv method. We can use it and specify all the values that should be interpreted as Nan

Comment: Good!  Keep an eye out for columns you intended to be numeric which end up as strings though.  Use `df.dtypes` to check this.  If you specify `na_values` correctly this may take care of that problem as well.

Comment: yes @Andrew_reece . Thank you for your pointers anyways. Will mention about "na_values" as my answer

Answer (score 1):

> pandas.isnull(obj)
>   Detect missing values (NaN in numeric arrays, None/NaN in object arrays)

Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.isnull.html

Your panda array is of type `string` and contains

- very short strings `["9","12, ...])"`and
- one longer string `[ ..., "null", ...]`

Neither of then is `None` as in `myvalue = None`.

If you convert them to ints and coerce the errors - the string `"null"` will become a `NaN` in your int-array - as it is not convertable to int. After that you can detect it with `isnull()`. You could also search your panda array for `"null"`-strings and replace them with `None` and keep all other columns as is.

Afterwards this `None` is detectable by `padans.isnull(.)` as well.

Answer (score 0):

for white space or null values represented as string can use space  in na_values

```
data1 = pd.read_csv(r"E:\intellipaat\r\customer_churn.csv",na_values=" ")
```